# Celery: One subtask in group always timesout

Tags: python, parallel-processing, timeout, celery

I'm experiencing a rather annoying behavior with Celery's [group](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#groups) feature.

I periodically need to check the IPs a bunch of hosts resolve to, just to make sure that said IPs haven't changed. In order to do that, I have a dictionary with the `< hostname, IPs >` I need to verify. For instance:

```
REQUIRED_HOSTS = {
    'google.com': {'173.194.46.64', '173.194.46.70', '173.194.46.71'},
    'stackoverflow.com': {'198.252.206.16'}
}
```

So the only thing to do is periodically iterate the `REQUIRED_HOSTS.keys()`, resolve the name and see if any of the IPs it resolves to is different to what I have recorded. (Not much of a brainer here)

In order to improve the efficiency a bit, each name is resolved in parallel. I created a subtask for that (it resolves using [dnspython](http://www.dnspython.org/examples.html)):

```
@my_tasks.task
def resolve_hostname(hostname, resolver=None):
    """ This subtask resolves the 'hostname' to its IP addresses. It's
    intended to be used in the 'compare_required_ips' function to resolve
    names in parallel """
    if resolver is None:
        resolver = dns.resolver.Resolver()
        resolver.nameservers = ['8.8.8.8' + '4.2.2.2'] + resolver.nameservers

    try:
        return (hostname,
                {hst.address for hst in resolver.query(hostname)})
    except Exception, e:
        logger.exception("Got %s when trying to resolve hostname=%s"
                         % (type(e), hostname))
        raise e
```

Now, the method that queries all the hostnames and spawns subtasks is the following:

```
@my_taks.task
def compare_required_ips():
    """ This method verifies that the IPs haven't changed. """
    retval = []
    resolver = dns.resolver.Resolver()
    resolver.nameservers = ['8.8.8.8' + '4.2.2.2'] + resolver.nameservers
    retrieved_hosts = dict.fromkeys(required_hosts.REQUIRED_HOSTS.keys())
    logger.info("Going to compare IPs for %s hostnames=%s"
                % (len(required_hosts.REQUIRED_HOSTS.keys()),
                   required_hosts.REQUIRED_HOSTS.keys()))
    ip_subtasks = group(
        [resolve_hostname.s(hostname, resolver=resolver)
         for hostname in required_hosts.REQUIRED_HOSTS.keys()]
    )()
    for hostname, ips in ip_subtasks.get(timeout=90):
        retrieved_hosts[hostname] = ips

    for hostname in required_hosts.REQUIRED_HOSTS:
        if (required_hosts.REQUIRED_HOSTS[hostname]
                != retrieved_hosts[hostname]):
            retval.append(hostname)
            logger.error(
                "IP resolution mismatch. hostname=%s resolve_target=%s"
                ", resolve_actual=%s (mismatch=%s)"
                % (hostname,
                   required_hosts.REQUIRED_HOSTS[hostname],
                   retrieved_hosts[hostname],
                   (required_hosts.REQUIRED_HOSTS[hostname]
                    ^ retrieved_hosts[hostname]))
            )
    return retval
```

Again, fairly easy... Just walk the `REQUIRED_HOSTS` keys (a.k.a. *hostnames*), spawn a subtask to resolve each of them and then collect the results with a 90 seconds timeout (which occurs in the line `for hostname, ips in ip_subtasks.get(timeout=90)` )

Now, the nuisance is that all the subtasks except one are successfully finished within that 90 seconds window. Then the parent task (`compare_required_ips`) fails because of the `timeout=90` and when this happens the subtask is successfully finished (immediately after the parent has failed). I have tried increasing and decreasing the timeout, and the subtask always takes whatever timeout I have specified in the `group` creation, making the main task report a failure.

I have also run the name resolution manually (without making it celery tasks, but using regular threading) and it resolves in milliseconds. Every time, with every test I try to make. I don't think it's an issue with the `dns.resolver.Resolver()` [class](http://www.dnspython.org/docs/1.12.0/dns.resolver.Resolver-class.html). Everything seems to point that this class resolves blazingly fast, but the subtask, or the group, or... someone in Celery doesn't know about it (one of the subtasks only, though)

I am using `celery==3.1.9`, `celery-with-redis==3.0` and `flower==0.6.0` to monitor.

Any help, hint or thing to test will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem might be a deadlock due to launching of synchronous sub tasks. `compare_required_ips` is a celery task. Inside this task you are waiting for a `group` of `resolve_hostname` tasks to complete which is really inefficient.

So you have to change this

```
ip_subtasks = group(
        [resolve_hostname.s(hostname, resolver=resolver)
         for hostname in required_hosts.REQUIRED_HOSTS.keys()]
    )()
```

to

```
ip_subtasks = group(
        [resolve_hostname.s(hostname, resolver=resolver)
         for hostname in required_hosts.REQUIRED_HOSTS.keys()]
    ).delay()
```

which launches all your tasks asynchronously and there by avoiding deadlock.

and

you shouldn't do a `ip_subtasks.get()` inside `compate_required_ips` task(even if `ip_subtask` takes only a nano second). You have to write a new function for that or use [celery task_success signal](http://docs.celeryq.org/en/latest/userguide/signals.html#signals).